# AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 - OSStatus error -12983

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have a video app that records and export to documents folder. But sometimes, especially after uploading video I take the error on the title.

What might be the wrong? What is OSStatus error -12983 ?

My code is a little bit longer. It will be added if you ask for.

Comment: Can you create a sample project and upload to dropbox, or somewhere else, so we can check it.

Comment: A -12983 typically means you left a decode stream running and did not close it properly when the app went into the background. You might have also dropped the last ref to a decoding object without shutting down the decoding session.